# getting black screen on iPad with an universal build

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, objective-c++

I'm developing a game that should run on all the iOS platforms but I'm getting a black screen on iPad.
I'm not using xib files since I'm building the window programmatically.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    // fullscreen window
    window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    glView = [[EAGLView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height)];
    [window addSubview:glView];

    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];

    [glView startAnimation];

    return YES;
}
```

It does receives the touces and play the music as well as the sfx but it shows only a black screen on iPad.
I've been looking for a solution to this but all the responses were about xib files (which I don't have).

Does anybody has experienced the same?
What could be the reason for the black screen on iPad?

Thanks.

Edit: forgot to say that I'm using OpengGL ES 1 with VBOs.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace this code line:

glView = [[EAGLView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

For more questions, you can check this [link](http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/tag/objective-c/)